# Android: How to set R.string value from strings.xml to a global constant in Kotlin?

Tags: android, xml, string, kotlin, constants

I'm new to Kotlin so maybe I'm missing something obvious, but I couldn't find an answer through Google.

How can I set the value of a Kotlin constant to a strings.xml resource value?  I've tried to do it like below but it's throwing the following error:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference

This is my code, the first val declaration fails:

```
class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

        private val STATUS_PREP = getString(R.string.status_prep) //THIS LINE FAILS
        private val STATUS_FIGHT = "fight" //res.getString(R.string.status_fight)
        private val STATUS_REST = "rest" //res.getString(R.string.status_rest)
        private val STATUS_COMPLETE = "complete" //res.getString(R.string.status_complete)
        private val STATUS_PAUSED = "paused" //res.getString(R.string.status_paused)
```

Answer (score 4):

Do this instead.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val STATUS_PREP: String by lazy {
        getString(R.string.status_prep_2) 
    }

    // OR

    private lateint var STATUS_PREP: String

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        // snip
        initString()
    }

    private fun initString() {
        STATUS_PREP = getString(R.string.status_prep) 
        // Init all your string here
    }
}
```

You are getting the exception because `context` is not initialized right after an instance of an activity is created.

Comment: Thanks, this works but I was hoping for a way to keep it as a constant val.

Comment: @user1429039 Then initialize by `lazy`

Answer (score -2):

You can create a class that inherits Application class and create inside it static field that will keep reference to application context like this:

```
class MyApplication: Application() {
    companion object {
         var context: Context? = null; private set
    }

     override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        context = applicationContext
     }
}
```

after that put it's name in AndroidManifest.xml like this:

```
<application
    android:name="com.yourpackage.MyApplication"
    ...
    // many other tags>
<application>
```

And then you can simply use it in everywhere in your app like this:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
     private val STATUS_PREP = MyApplication.context!!.getString(R.string.status_prep)
}
```

Comment: Holding on to static context is a bad practice

Comment: @E.T. it's a bad practice in case of the context is an instance of activity context, it can lead to memory leaks, so you must don't do it with activity context, but in case of application context we have only one instance of context per app, so using this approach we have sort of a singleton for application context and i don't see any disadvantages of this approach. Can you explain to me why it's a bad practice?

Comment: @easy_breezy A quick Google search answers your question, but I will refer you to these two posts, one on philosophicalhacker.com and the other on Reddit: 
https://www.philosophicalhacker.com/2015/07/14/why-static-references-to-application-contexts-are-probably-not-the-best-idea/
https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/4b0mru/any_disadvantage_on_keeping_a_static_app_context/
As mentioned in these, statically holding application context most likely will not affect your app negatively, but there are disadvantages to this approach. It is better to pass context or use dependency injection.